# Does bayesian neural network good for text/document classification?

Tags: bayesian, neural-networks, classification, bayesian-network

I've tried to do my research online, but I find most of them are **image classification**. I guess that is because nature(downside) of Bayesian DL: it's significantly slower than traditional DL, then few people use it for text/doc classification. Am I right? Or is there a more specific reason for that.

Please correct me if I'm wrong/ missing some text/document implement on code during my research, thanks guys!

Comment: Hi, could you share your experience on Bayesian Neural Network for text/document classification? Which feature extraction technique you have used?

Comment: I am also and still interested in this.